# How can I fix Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error?

Tags: typescript, api, express, httprequest, query-string

I have 2 questions, made a searching query by using `express get method` and it's working fine it gets the requested tickets, the thing is I keep getting errors even the method is working
so the first question is why do I keep getting those errors and how can I fix it?

Console log:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)       
    at ServerResponse.json (C:Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at C:Project\server\index.ts:63:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

Code:

```
  app.get(APIPath, (req, res) => {
    //@ts-ignore
    const search:String = req.query.search;
  if(search !== undefined){
    const filteredTickets = tempData.filter((t) => (t.title.toLowerCase() + t.content.toLowerCase()).includes(search.toLowerCase()));
    res.send(filteredTickets);
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  const page: number = req.query.page || 1;

  const paginatedData = tempData.slice((page - 1) * dataProps.getPageSize(), page * dataProps.getPageSize());

  console.log("Server: Page " + page + " was sent!");
  console.log("Server: Search query: " + search)

  res.send(paginatedData);
});
```

As you can see I made 2 queries in the same function, the page query works perfectly fine and the reason I tried to combine them is because I want to still be able to have pages after I search for other parameters (page limit is 20), but currently they are not working together because I don't know how to do that.
That brings up the second question, How can I combine both of the queries so it would look like that `https://localhost:3000/?page=[Page]/?search=[Search request]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call `res.send()` more than once. `res.send()` doesn't stop execution of the function on its own, so you have to return manually.

```
return res.send(filteredTickets);
```

Otherwise the function continues execution and gets to the second `res.send()` call.